# How to select multipe files for vimdif using vim?

Tags: vimdiff

Suppose I have some files in a folder. I browse the folder using vim `vim myfolder`. It lists the files, now I want to know how I can select two files and then open them in comparison mode (two tabs, ...)

Answer (score 0):

When you opened the folder using vim, `vim thefolder`

- navigate to each file using arrow keys and press `mf`, it marks the files,
- then press `md`, it calls vimdiff on the selected files (up
  to 3 files).